# Gallery is not included in body

Tags: html, css

I just finished working on an image gallery in a text editor, but when I put it on my website it didn't go inside the website. The container is supposed to be the full length of the screen with the header at the top, then the body with the gallery, then the footer. But my code does not include the gallery into the body. I have tried everything I can think of. It is probably just a tsupid mistake, but it isn't the zindexs, it isn't the overflow, I don't know what it is. My website is at http://spencedesign.netau.net/singapore-gallery.html Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a website that will validate all your code. I'd strongly recommend doing some more building by hand (the hard way) before you copy and paste any more or you're just going to end up with more frustrating issues like this.

w3.org is hands down one of the best resources for looking up syntax and how to use various pieces of HTML among many other languages.

[List of Problems](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://spencedesign.netau.net/singapore-gallery.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1)